# PowerShell: Format and sort environment variables

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Using PowerShell I can get all (current process) environment variables and format and sort them:

```
gci env: | %{"{0}={1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Value} | sort
```

which gives:

```
a=foo
b=bar
c=baz
```

But that gives all process variables, and I want only the user variables, so I  do:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User") | %{"{0}={1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Value} | sort
```

But that outputs this only:

```
=
```

The `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")` works, the stuff after is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")` returns a hash table, not a collection of objects. There are several ways to get what you want. Here is one:

```
([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")).GetEnumerator() | %{'{0} = {1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value}
```